# New Column on Custom List

Tags: column

I need to add a column to my custom list that does NOT need to show up on the form. It is a field that will be there for owners to use for documentation purposes. It is okay for this column to show to all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you'll create your column as desired. Then in the List Settings -> Advanced Settings, you enable the Management of content types.

You should then see a new section in the List Settings with the default list content type. Click the title of the content type, most likely its Item, to go into the properties. Click your column and toggle it to be Hidden.

The field will not appear on the forms but will show in the views. The value can be modified by using the datasheet/quick edit mode.